# update time data from VB in Mysql workbench without click refresh

Tags: mysql-workbench, timestamp, visual-studio-2010

my database get data from VB.net every second. The problem is when VB send data to my mysql workbench, MySQL can't automatically show this data in result window. So I must click refresh tab in result grid every second. Is there any query to make it refresh automatically when the data come? because I need to know when the time data arrive in my database. I try use timestamp but timestamp just record the tima when I clicked the refresh button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the correct answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51472/how-to-auto-refresh-re-run-a-query-every-few-seconds). It won't work through MySQL Workbench, but will provide a data refreshing capability from the command line. The answer is for a Windows based system, so if you're running Linux/Unix, adjust the parameters appropriately.